# Compare part of node xml files using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, compare

I want to compare a part of the xml-tree of two files (GPO->Computer from a GPOReport).

```
$Xml1 = Get-Object $Path1
$Xml2 = Get-Object $Path2

Compare-Object ($Xml1) -DifferenceObject ($Xml2)
```

gives the complete differences from the file. But I want only part of the node.

Comment: What is `Get-Object` and what does it do?

Comment: Sorry typo....I mean Get-Content

Answer (score 1):

Comparing trees (ie. an XML document) is a bit more complicated than comparing two lists (like the lines in two files).

It's unclear from your question how extensive a comparison you're looking for here, but if you're only interested in testing a single value or attribute between two XML documents, the easiest is probably with `Select-Xml`:

```
$xml1 = [xml]@'
<root>
  <nodegroup>
    <node name="myNode">SomeValue</node>
  </nodegroup>
</root>
'@
$xml2 = [xml]@'
<root>
  <nodegroup>
    <node name="myNode">SomeOtherValue</node>
  </nodegroup>
</root>
'@

$res1,$res2 = $xml1,$xml2 |Select-Xml -XPath 'root/nodegroup/node[@name = "myNode"]'

if($res1.Node.InnerText -eq $res2.Node.InnerText){
    # the inner text value of the selected node is the same in both documents
}
```

Comment: My goal is to compare a GPO template xml <computer> and <user> with those we actualy imported at a domain. So I can check the GPO has the correct value's. Because those GPO's are imported on many domains.